# Display most popular posts of category

Tags: php, categories, popular-posts

Right now in my slider I'm showing most popular post by views. However, I want to shop most popular post by views only for a certain category? The category id I want to use is "10". How would I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```html
<div id="slider-food"> 
<?php 
$carousel_cat = get_theme_mod('carousel_setting','1'); 
$carousel_count = get_theme_mod('count_setting','4'); 
$month = date('m'); 
$year = date('Y'); 
$new_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC','monthnum'=>$month,'year'=>$year )); 
?> 
<?php if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
<?php while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?> 
<div class="item"> 
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('popular-posts'); ?>
    <h2><a class="popular-category" 
        <?php 
        $categories = get_the_category(); 
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';

        if ($categories) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;
            }
            echo trim($output, $separator);
        }

        ?></a></h2>
 <p>
     <a class="popular-excerpt" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></a>
                </p>
</div> 
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
<?php else : ?> 
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Popular Posts Found ' ); ?></p> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding `'cat'=> 10` to your query?

```
$new_query = new WP_Query(  array(
   'posts_per_page' => $carousel_count, 
   'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'monthnum'=> $month,
   'year'=> $year, 
   'cat'=> 10
));
```